# web service proxy encodes angle brackets

Tags: c#, wcf, soap-client

i am a beginner, there is a web service which i had added as a web reference and working perfectly, but in one function, i have to post `"<string>217268</string>"` as a string. it looks like

```
RegionTravelReport("username", "password1", "password2", "06122016000000", "06212016235959", "", "<string>217268</string>", "1", "0", "TR", "0");
```

it doesn't work, when i sniff soap envelope with fiddler i see it encodes like `&lt;string&gt;217268&lt;/string&gt;`

is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: `<` and `>` are special characters in XML, and what you're seeing is the encoding so that when the XML is parsed, it will be parsed properly.  The service should have no problem deserializing that.

Comment: i know it should be but it doesn't and i don't have any control over web service, so i have to find a way to post soap envelope with the unencoded angle brackets.